# Adding Section without Number to Minitoc using \mtcaddsection?

Tags: minitoc

I'm trying to get the below code to work, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```latex
\section*{ASTERISK SECTION}
\mtcaddsection[ASTERISK SECTION]
```

I can get `\mtcaddchapter[ASTERISK CHAPTER]` to add that to the main TOC how I want without adding a number or affecting the chapter count:

[image]

How do I get an entry in the `minitoc` for an un-numbered entry for the `\section*{ASTERISK SECTION}`?

[image]

Here's my current MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book} % [text size]{document type}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, blindtext} %for testing
\usepackage{minitoc} % Get chapter level TOC
\renewcommand{\mtctitle}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}

\setcounter{parttocdepth}{4} % set minitoc sublevel
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % to get X.X.X.X
\mtcsetrules{*}{off}
\dominitoc
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
    \chapter{FIRST CHAPTER}\label{ch5}
    
    \minitoc{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}\newpage
    
    \section{Minitoc C1 S1}
    \blindtext \blindtext
    \subsection{C1 SS1}
    \blindtext \blindtext
    \subsection{C1 SS2}
    \blindtext \blindtext
    \subsection{C1 SS3}
    \blindtext \blindtext
    \subsubsection{C1 SS3 S1}
    \blindtext \blindtext
    \section{Minitoc Section 2}
    \blindtext \blindtext
    \subsection{My Section  2 Subsection 1}
    \blindtext \blindtext
    \subsection{My Section  2 Subsection 2}
    \blindtext \blindtext
    \subsection{My Section  2 Subsection 3}
    \blindtext \blindtext
    \subsubsection{My Section  2 Subsection 3  Subsubsection 1}
    \blindtext \blindtext
    \section*{ASTERISK SECTION}
%   \mtcaddsection[ASTERISK SECTION]
    \mtcaddchapter[ASTERISK CHAPTER]
    \blindtext \blindtext
    \chapter{SECOND CHAPTER}
    \blindtext \blindtext
\end{document}
```